# Can I buy White Labs "Platinum Strains" yeasts in their seasonal availability window every year?

Tags: yeast

I am looking at the White Labs WLP076 (Old Sonoma Ale), and see that it is available May-June.  My LHBS, which also happens to be a natl. mail order shop, does not have it available. I see some online shops that have it, but I am leery of its freshness. Are the Platinum Strains yeasts one-time special releases, or do they come out each year?

Sorry for such a rookie question, but I have not bought liquid yeast before, the web page for that yeast at White Labs is not working, and their web site is not really clear on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIUI, they're generally "one-time" releases that might come back in the future if customer response was sufficiently good. For instance, Wyeast 3726 used to be a "Private Collection" offering, and is now part of their regular lineup; Denny's Favorite 50 (Wyeast 1450) the same.  Wyeast vs. White Labs, but it's all the same game.

I would not recommend using liquid yeast produced in June, especially for your first liquid yeast experience.

Comment: For clarity, by "liquid yeast produced in June", you mean "liquid yeast which is older than 4 months", I presume?

Comment: Yes, viability is way low at that point; yeastcalc.com says 29%.  You can get the cell count back up with enough starter wort/steps, but you're working against the odds.